# Depending on msbuild target names

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-core, target

Target names from Microsoft target files(*C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks*) are not officially documented but they are not hidden too.

We could depend on them and use in our Before/AfterTargets or DependsOnTargets as they will only change through msbuild or Visual Studio major versions.

When they change through versions, we could write targets that depend conditionally on targets for specific versions, i.e. '$(MSBuildVersion)' == '15.6.82'

They are listed by someone [here](https://gist.github.com/StevenLiekens/cae70cce25344ba47b86).

So, is it a good practice to depend on target names from Microsoft target files?

Answer (score 0):

The only ones you should be using are well known, basic generic targets like "Build" and "Clean".

I've been doing builds for years, and never had to rely on anything deeper than that. If you are, you're doing something wrong.